# Select and count the length of unchecked checkboxes using each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I only know how to check checked, have no idea how to include the ! (not).. I want to check how many checkboxes are left unchecked when a checkbox is checked..

```
$('ul li input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      var count = 0;      
      var lenghtOfChecked = count++;
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This way:

```
var lengthOfUnchecked = $('ul li input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vq9A9/

Comment: change() can use to check checked and unchecked, input etc.. just for properties right?

Answer (score 1):

use `.not(:checked)`

```
$('ul li input:checkbox').not(':checked').each
```